# Spring Boot handle JWT manually

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin, jwt, openid-connect

I'm currently working with OpenID and JWT for authentication and try to work it out manually - just for understanding, don't worry ;-)

So i created a `Filter` which extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` but it is not called after getting the JWT token. This is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {


    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .addFilterAfter(OpenIdConnectFilter("/secure"), OpenIDAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }


}
```

having a breakpoint in the `attemptAuthentication` of the `OpenIdConnectFilter` but it is never called, even no exception nothing .. just 403 on client side.

Edit:

So do you have any idea how to "intercept" the incoming request with my OpenIDConnectFilter to do the verification there?

Comment: Me too! Did you fix it?

Comment: sorry no .. up to now, most of that spring security stuff is quite obfuscating to me :-)